# When is savedInstanceState really used?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I'm new to Android, and i'm having some troubles with savedInstanceState and managing the lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle
I read the article about lifecycle, but I don't really know WHEN the process is killed, and my nice savedInstanceSate will be used ! I can press "HOME", but it only launches "onPause" then "onResume" I think.

If I go to Menu->Settings->Application->Manage Application->My application name->Force Stop, it is still seen as a running app, but when I relaunch it, I go back to the "first activity". So it is like closing the application, it's not "Killing the process" as I would like, if I understand well.

So here are my questions :

1)How can I be sure my process have been killed (so my app will use the savedIntanceState when restarted) ?

2)How can I force the process to be killed, to test if my savedInstanceState are well programmed ?

3)When after having been "killed", the app is restarted and the "onCreate" is called (with a savedInstanceState!=null that time), can I still acces to the Intent Extra informations I gave when I called the Activity, or the infomations of the Intent were deleted when the process is killed ?
Said differently, must I include in my saveInstanceState a copy of what was stored in the Intent Extra ?

I hope I'm clear enough ;)

Comment: You can kill the process in adb shell using kill <pid>.

Answer (score 1):

1) All you need to worry about is overriding your Activity's `onSaveInstanceState()`.  Android will call that before it kills your process.

2) You need to setup an [Android test project](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html).  Then, create a test which extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, and you can get an `Instrumentation` object by calling `getInstrumentation().  From there, you can call [Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#callActivityOnCreate%28android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle%29)  and pass a Bundle object to use for testing.

3) I am pretty sure that you will have store the extras in the savedInstanceState bundle.